# Refreshing page enter record in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am making a page in which user will enter task which he/she wants to do in future. When ever after posting the data I refresh the page it makes a new record but I don't want to create a new record upon refreshing that particular page.

Code of my controller is

```
 public function addToDoList(Request $request)
{
    $id = DB::table('doctors')->where('name',Auth::user()->name)->first();
    if(Input::get('toDo'))
        {
        ToDoList::create([
        'toDoWork' => $request->todolist,
        'doctor_id' => $id->id,
    ]);
        }

        $request->toDo = null;

    $todolists = Doctor::find($id->id)->todolists;
    return view('/doctorPanel/doctorHome',['todolists' => $todolists]);
}
```

Route is

```
Route::post('/doctorPanel/doctorHome','doctorHomeController@addToDoList')->name('toDoList')->middleware('doctor');
```

Please tell me what I should do to stop creating record upon refreshing the page.

Comment: After creating the item, you should redirect from the `POST` route to a to a `GET` route that displays the newly added item. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: as answered below you should use: `return redirect()->back();` instead of `return view()`

Answer (score 3):

user redirect instead of return view
after creating the record redirect to your list url or route

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

here login is your route 
or use

```
  return redirect()->back();
```